# Varnish compiler will not start when providing correct .vcl file

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I installed Varnish with command `apt-get install varnish`

Varnish version is `varnishd (varnish-6.2.1 revision 9f8588e4ab785244e06c3446fe09bf9db5dd8753)`

I try to validate my VCL file with command `varnishd -C -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl`

My VCL file:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {

}

sub vcl_backend_response {

}

sub vcl_deliver {

}
```

This is the response I get, seems like it just echoes out varnish .c file:

```
/* ---===### Location Counters ###===---*/

#define VGC_NREFS 35

static const struct vrt_ref VGC_ref[VGC_NREFS] = {
  [  1] = { 0,      796,   26,   1,  "}" },
  [  2] = { 0,     1025,   33,   1,  "}" },
  [  3] = { 0,     1223,   40,   1,  "}" },
  [  4] = { 1,     1605,   38,   5,  "if" },
  [  5] = { 1,     1719,   40,   9,  "return" },
  [  6] = { 1,     1750,   42,   5,  "if" },
  [  7] = { 1,     1890,   46,   9,  "return" },
  [  8] = { 1,     1921,   48,   5,  "if" },
  [  9] = { 1,     2225,   57,   9,  "return" },
  [ 10] = { 1,     2251,   60,   5,  "if" },
  [ 11] = { 1,     2366,   62,   9,  "return" },
  [ 12] = { 1,     2391,   64,   5,  "if" },
  [ 13] = { 1,     2487,   66,   9,  "return" },
  [ 14] = { 1,     2512,   68,   5,  "return" },
  [ 15] = { 1,     2819,   77,   5,  "return" },
  [ 16] = { 1,     2856,   81,   5,  "return" },
  [ 17] = { 1,     2894,   85,   5,  "hash_data" },
  [ 18] = { 1,     2947,   87,   9,  "hash_data" },
  [ 19] = { 1,     2994,   89,   9,  "hash_data" },
  [ 20] = { 1,     3066,   95,   5,  "return" },
  [ 21] = { 1,     3118,   99,   5,  "return" },
  [ 22] = { 1,     3158,  103,   5,  "return" },
  [ 23] = { 1,     3199,  107,   5,  "return" },
  [ 24] = { 1,     3316,  114,   5,  "set" },
  [ 25] = { 1,     3907,  138,   5,  "if" },
  [ 26] = { 1,     3944,  139,   9,  "unset" },
  [ 27] = { 1,     3972,  141,   5,  "return" },
  [ 28] = { 1,     4022,  145,   5,  "if" },
  [ 29] = { 1,     4055,  146,   9,  "return" },
  [ 30] = { 1,     4407,  154,   9,  "set" },
  [ 31] = { 1,     4479,  157,   5,  "return" },
  [ 32] = { 1,     4528,  161,   5,  "set" },
  [ 33] = { 1,     5127,  185,   5,  "return" },
  [ 34] = { 1,     5162,  189,   5,  "return" },
};

/* ---===### VCC generated .h code ###===---*/

static struct vsmw_cluster *vsc_cluster;

extern const struct VCL_conf VCL_conf;

static VCL_BACKEND vgc_backend_default;

/* "127.0.0.1 8080" -> 127.0.0.1 */
static const unsigned long long suckaddr_0[4] = {
    0x901f00024b1e9335ULL,
    0x000000000100007fULL,
    0x0000000000000000ULL,
    0x0000000000000000ULL
};

static const struct vrt_backend vgc_dir_priv_vgc_backend_default = {
        .magic = VRT_BACKEND_MAGIC,
        .vcl_name = "default",
        .ipv4_suckaddr = (const struct suckaddr *)(const void*)suckaddr_0,
        .ipv4_addr = "127.0.0.1",
        .port = "8080",
        .path = (void *) 0,
        .hosthdr = "127.0.0.1",
};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_REQ_host =
    { HDR_REQ, "\005host:"};
static void *VGC_re_1;
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_REQ_Authorization =
    { HDR_REQ, "\016Authorization:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_REQ_Cookie =
    { HDR_REQ, "\007Cookie:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_RESP_Content_2d_Type =
    { HDR_RESP, "\015Content-Type:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_RESP_Retry_2d_After =
    { HDR_RESP, "\014Retry-After:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_BERESP_Set_2d_Cookie =
    { HDR_BERESP, "\013Set-Cookie:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_BERESP_Surrogate_2d_control =
    { HDR_BERESP, "\022Surrogate-control:"};
static void *VGC_re_2;
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_BERESP_Cache_2d_Control =
    { HDR_BERESP, "\016Cache-Control:"};
static void *VGC_re_3;
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_BERESP_Vary =
    { HDR_BERESP, "\005Vary:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_BERESP_Content_2d_Type =
    { HDR_BERESP, "\015Content-Type:"};
static const struct gethdr_s VGC_HDR_BERESP_Retry_2d_After =
    { HDR_BERESP, "\014Retry-After:"};

vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_backend_error;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_backend_fetch;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_backend_response;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_deliver;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_fini;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_hash;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_hit;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_init;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_miss;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_pass;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_pipe;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_purge;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_recv;
vcl_func_f VGC_function_vcl_synth;

static unsigned vgc_inistep;
static unsigned vgc_warmupstep;

/* ---===### VCC generated .c code ###===---*/

#define END_ if (*ctx->handling) return

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_backend_error(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 160 Pos 23) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 32);
      END_;
      VRT_SetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Content_2d_Type,
        "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      VRT_SetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Retry_2d_After,
        "5",
        vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      VRT_l_beresp_body(ctx, 
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
        "<html>\n"
        "  <head>\n"
        "    <title>",
        VRT_INT_string(ctx, VRT_r_beresp_status(ctx)),
        " ",
        VRT_r_beresp_reason(ctx),
        "</title>\n"
        "  </head>\n"
        "  <body>\n"
        "    <h1>Error ",
        VRT_INT_string(ctx, VRT_r_beresp_status(ctx)),
        " ",
        VRT_r_beresp_reason(ctx),
        "</h1>\n"
        "    <p>",
        VRT_r_beresp_reason(ctx),
        "</p>\n"
        "    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>\n"
        "    <p>XID: ",
        VRT_r_bereq_xid(ctx),
        "</p>\n"
        "    <hr>\n"
        "    <p>Varnish cache server</p>\n"
        "  </body>\n"
        "</html>\n"
        "",
        vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_DELIVER);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_backend_fetch(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 137 Pos 23) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 25);
      END_;
      if (
        (0 == VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_bereq_method(ctx), "GET"))
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 26);
          END_;
          VRT_u_bereq_body(ctx);
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 27);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_FETCH);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_backend_response(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 28 Pos 26) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 2);
      END_;
    }
  }
  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 144 Pos 26) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 28);
      END_;
      if (
        VRT_r_bereq_uncacheable(ctx)
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 29);
          END_;
          VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_DELIVER);
          END_;
        }
      else if (
        (
          (VRT_r_beresp_ttl(ctx) <= (0) * 1)
        ||
          (VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Set_2d_Cookie) != 0)
        ||
          VRT_re_match(ctx, VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Surrogate_2d_control), VGC_re_2)
        ||
          ((
            !((VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Surrogate_2d_control) != 0))
          &&
            VRT_re_match(ctx, VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Cache_2d_Control), VGC_re_3)
          ))
        ||
          (0 == VRT_strcmp(VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_BERESP_Vary), "*"))
        )
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 30);
          END_;
          VRT_l_beresp_ttl(ctx, 
            (120) * 1
          );
          END_;
          VRT_l_beresp_uncacheable(ctx, 
            (0==0)
          );
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 31);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_DELIVER);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_deliver(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 35 Pos 17) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 3);
      END_;
    }
  }
  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 106 Pos 17) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 23);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_DELIVER);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_fini(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 188 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 34);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_OK);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_hash(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 84 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 17);
      END_;
      VRT_hashdata(ctx,
        VRT_r_req_url(ctx),
      vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      if (
        (VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_REQ_host) != 0)
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 18);
          END_;
          VRT_hashdata(ctx,
            VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_REQ_host),
          vrt_magic_string_end
          );
          END_;
        }
      else
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 19);
          END_;
          VRT_hashdata(ctx,
            VRT_IP_string(ctx, VRT_r_server_ip(ctx)),
          vrt_magic_string_end
          );
          END_;
        }
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_LOOKUP);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_hit(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 98 Pos 13) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 21);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_DELIVER);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_init(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 184 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 33);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_OK);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_miss(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 102 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 22);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_FETCH);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_pass(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 80 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 16);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_FETCH);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_pipe(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 71 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 15);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_PIPE);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_purge(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 94 Pos 15) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 20);
      END_;
      VRT_synth(ctx,
        200
        ,
        "Purged"
      );
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_SYNTH);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_recv(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 21 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 1);
      END_;
    }
  }
  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 37 Pos 14) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 4);
      END_;
      if (
        (0 == VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "PRI"))
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 5);
          END_;
          VRT_synth(ctx,
            405
            ,
            (const char*)0
          );
          VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_SYNTH);
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 6);
      END_;
      if (
        (
          !((VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_REQ_host) != 0))
        &&
          (VRT_r_req_esi_level(ctx) == 0)
        &&
          VRT_re_match(ctx, VRT_r_req_proto(ctx), VGC_re_1)
        )
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 7);
          END_;
          VRT_synth(ctx,
            400
            ,
            (const char*)0
          );
          VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_SYNTH);
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 8);
      END_;
      if (
        (
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "GET"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "HEAD"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "PUT"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "POST"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "TRACE"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "OPTIONS"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "DELETE"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "PATCH"))
        )
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 9);
          END_;
          VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_PIPE);
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 10);
      END_;
      if (
        (
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "GET"))
        &&
          (0 != VRT_strcmp(VRT_r_req_method(ctx), "HEAD"))
        )
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 11);
          END_;
          VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_PASS);
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 12);
      END_;
      if (
        (
          (VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_REQ_Authorization) != 0)
        ||
          (VRT_GetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_REQ_Cookie) != 0)
        )
      )
        {
          VRT_count(ctx, 13);
          END_;
          VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_PASS);
          END_;
        }
      VRT_count(ctx, 14);
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_HASH);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

void v_matchproto_(vcl_func_f)
VGC_function_vcl_synth(VRT_CTX)
{

  /* ... from ('Builtin' Line 113 Pos 15) */
  {
    {
      VRT_count(ctx, 24);
      END_;
      VRT_SetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_RESP_Content_2d_Type,
        "text/html; charset=utf-8",
        vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      VRT_SetHdr(ctx, &VGC_HDR_RESP_Retry_2d_After,
        "5",
        vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      VRT_l_resp_body(ctx, 
        "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"
        "<html>\n"
        "  <head>\n"
        "    <title>",
        VRT_INT_string(ctx, VRT_r_resp_status(ctx)),
        " ",
        VRT_r_resp_reason(ctx),
        "</title>\n"
        "  </head>\n"
        "  <body>\n"
        "    <h1>Error ",
        VRT_INT_string(ctx, VRT_r_resp_status(ctx)),
        " ",
        VRT_r_resp_reason(ctx),
        "</h1>\n"
        "    <p>",
        VRT_r_resp_reason(ctx),
        "</p>\n"
        "    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>\n"
        "    <p>XID: ",
        VRT_r_req_xid(ctx),
        "</p>\n"
        "    <hr>\n"
        "    <p>Varnish cache server</p>\n"
        "  </body>\n"
        "</html>\n"
        "",
        vrt_magic_string_end
      );
      END_;
      VRT_handling(ctx, VCL_RET_DELIVER);
      END_;
    }
  }
}

static int
VGC_Load(VRT_CTX)
{

        vgc_inistep = 0;
        size_t ndirector = 1UL;

        /* 1 */
        vsc_cluster = VRT_VSM_Cluster_New(ctx,
            ndirector * VRT_backend_vsm_need(ctx));
        if (vsc_cluster == 0)
                return(1);
        vgc_inistep = 1;

        /* 2 */
        vgc_backend_default =
            VRT_new_backend_clustered(ctx, vsc_cluster,
                &vgc_dir_priv_vgc_backend_default);
        vgc_inistep = 2;

        /* 3 */
        VRT_re_init(&VGC_re_1, "^(\?i)HTTP/1.1");
        vgc_inistep = 3;

        /* 4 */
        VRT_re_init(&VGC_re_2, "(\?i)no-store");
        vgc_inistep = 4;

        /* 5 */
        VRT_re_init(&VGC_re_3, "(\?i:no-cache|no-store|private)");
        vgc_inistep = 5;

        /* 6 */
        VGC_function_vcl_init(ctx);

        vgc_inistep = 6;


        if (*ctx->handling != VCL_RET_OK)
                return(1);
        return(0);
}

static int
VGC_Discard(VRT_CTX)
{

        switch (vgc_inistep) {
                case 6:
                        VGC_function_vcl_fini(ctx);
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 5:
                        VRT_re_fini(VGC_re_3);
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 4:
                        VRT_re_fini(VGC_re_2);
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 3:
                        VRT_re_fini(VGC_re_1);
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 2:
                        VRT_delete_backend(ctx, &vgc_backend_default);
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 1:
                        VRT_VSM_Cluster_Destroy(ctx, &vsc_cluster);
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                default:
                        break;
        }

        switch (vgc_inistep) {
                case 6:
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 5:
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 4:
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 3:
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 2:
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 1:
                        /* FALLTHROUGH */
                default:
                        break;
        }

        return (0);
}

static int
VGC_Event(VRT_CTX, enum vcl_event_e ev)
{
        if (ev == VCL_EVENT_LOAD)
                return (VGC_Load(ctx));
        if (ev == VCL_EVENT_DISCARD)
                return (VGC_Discard(ctx));

        (void)vgc_warmupstep;
        return (0);
}

const struct VCL_conf VCL_conf = {
        .magic = VCL_CONF_MAGIC,
        .syntax = 40,
        .event_vcl = VGC_Event,
        .default_director = &vgc_backend_default,
        .ref = VGC_ref,
        .nref = VGC_NREFS,
        .nsrc = VGC_NSRCS,
        .srcname = srcname,
        .srcbody = srcbody,
        .nvmod = 0,
        .backend_error_func = VGC_function_vcl_backend_error,
        .backend_fetch_func = VGC_function_vcl_backend_fetch,
        .backend_response_func = VGC_function_vcl_backend_response,
        .deliver_func = VGC_function_vcl_deliver,
        .fini_func = VGC_function_vcl_fini,
        .hash_func = VGC_function_vcl_hash,
        .hit_func = VGC_function_vcl_hit,
        .init_func = VGC_function_vcl_init,
        .miss_func = VGC_function_vcl_miss,
        .pass_func = VGC_function_vcl_pass,
        .pipe_func = VGC_function_vcl_pipe,
        .purge_func = VGC_function_vcl_purge,
        .recv_func = VGC_function_vcl_recv,
        .synth_func = VGC_function_vcl_synth,
};

/*
 * Symbol Table
 *
 * none      VOID       41 41 acl
 * none      VOID       41 41 backend
 * action    VOID       40 41 ban
 * var       HTTP        0 99 bereq
 * var       BACKEND     0 99 bereq.backend
 * var       DURATION    0 99 bereq.between_bytes_timeout
 * var       BODY        0 99 bereq.body
 * var       DURATION    0 99 bereq.connect_timeout
 * var       DURATION    0 99 bereq.first_byte_timeout
 * var       BLOB        0 99 bereq.hash
 * none      HEADER      0 99 bereq.http*
 * var       BOOL        0 99 bereq.is_bgfetch
 * var       STRING      0 99 bereq.method
 * var       STRING      0 40 bereq.proto
 * var       STRING     41 99 bereq.proto
 * var       INT         0 99 bereq.retries
 * var       BOOL        0 99 bereq.uncacheable
 * var       STRING      0 99 bereq.url
 * var       STRING      0 99 bereq.xid
 * var       HTTP        0 99 beresp
 * var       DURATION    0 99 beresp.age
 * var       BACKEND     0 99 beresp.backend
 * var       IP          0 40 beresp.backend.ip
 * var       STRING      0 99 beresp.backend.name
 * var       BODY        0 99 beresp.body
 * var       BOOL        0 99 beresp.do_esi
 * var       BOOL        0 99 beresp.do_gunzip
 * var       BOOL        0 99 beresp.do_gzip
 * var       BOOL        0 99 beresp.do_stream
 * var       STRING      0 99 beresp.filters
 * var       DURATION    0 99 beresp.grace
 * none      HEADER      0 99 beresp.http*
 * var       HEADER     40 40 beresp.http.Cache-Control
 * var       HEADER     40 40 beresp.http.Content-Type
 * var       HEADER     40 40 beresp.http.Retry-After
 * var       HEADER     40 40 beresp.http.Set-Cookie
 * var       HEADER     40 40 beresp.http.Surrogate-control
 * var       HEADER     40 40 beresp.http.Vary
 * var       DURATION    0 99 beresp.keep
 * var       STRING      0 40 beresp.proto
 * var       STRING     41 99 beresp.proto
 * var       STRING      0 99 beresp.reason
 * var       INT         0 99 beresp.status
 * var       STEVEDORE   0 99 beresp.storage
 * var       STRING      0 40 beresp.storage_hint
 * var       DURATION    0 99 beresp.ttl
 * var       BOOL        0 99 beresp.uncacheable
 * var       BOOL        0 99 beresp.was_304
 * action    VOID       40 41 call
 * none      VOID        0 99 client
 * var       STRING      0 99 client.identity
 * var       IP          0 99 client.ip
 * none      VOID       41 41 default
 * func      BOOL       40 41 false
 * action    VOID       40 41 hash_data
 * action    VOID       40 41 if
 * none      VOID       41 41 import
 * none      VOID        0 99 local
 * var       STRING     41 99 local.endpoint
 * var       IP          0 99 local.ip
 * var       STRING     41 99 local.socket
 * action    VOID       40 41 new
 * var       TIME        0 99 now
 * none      VOID        0 99 obj
 * var       DURATION    0 99 obj.age
 * var       DURATION    0 99 obj.grace
 * var       INT         0 99 obj.hits
 * none      HEADER      0 99 obj.http*
 * var       DURATION    0 99 obj.keep
 * var       STRING      0 99 obj.proto
 * var       STRING      0 99 obj.reason
 * var       INT         0 99 obj.status
 * var       STEVEDORE   0 99 obj.storage
 * var       DURATION    0 99 obj.ttl
 * var       BOOL        0 99 obj.uncacheable
 * none      VOID       41 41 probe
 * func      STRING     40 41 regsub
 * func      STRING     40 41 regsuball
 * none      VOID        0 99 remote
 * var       IP          0 99 remote.ip
 * var       HTTP        0 99 req
 * var       BACKEND     0 99 req.backend_hint
 * var       BOOL        0 99 req.can_gzip
 * var       BOOL        0 40 req.esi
 * var       INT         0 99 req.esi_level
 * var       DURATION    0 99 req.grace
 * var       BLOB        0 99 req.hash
 * var       BOOL        0 99 req.hash_always_miss
 * var       BOOL        0 99 req.hash_ignore_busy
 * none      HEADER      0 99 req.http*
 * var       HEADER     40 40 req.http.Authorization
 * var       HEADER     40 40 req.http.Cookie
 * var       HEADER     40 40 req.http.host
 * var       BOOL        0 99 req.is_hitmiss
 * var       BOOL        0 99 req.is_hitpass
 * var       STRING      0 99 req.method
 * var       STRING      0 40 req.proto
 * var       STRING     41 99 req.proto
 * var       INT         0 99 req.restarts
 * var       STEVEDORE   0 99 req.storage
 * var       DURATION    0 99 req.ttl
 * var       STRING      0 99 req.url
 * var       STRING      0 99 req.xid
 * none      VOID        0 99 req_top
 * none      HEADER      0 99 req_top.http*
 * var       STRING      0 99 req_top.method
 * var       STRING      0 99 req_top.proto
 * var       STRING      0 99 req_top.url
 * var       HTTP        0 99 resp
 * var       BODY        0 99 resp.body
 * var       BOOL       41 99 resp.do_esi
 * var       STRING      0 99 resp.filters
 * none      HEADER      0 99 resp.http*
 * var       HEADER     40 40 resp.http.Content-Type
 * var       HEADER     40 40 resp.http.Retry-After
 * var       BOOL        0 99 resp.is_streaming
 * var       STRING      0 40 resp.proto
 * var       STRING     41 99 resp.proto
 * var       STRING      0 99 resp.reason
 * var       INT         0 99 resp.status
 * action    VOID       40 41 return
 * none      VOID        0 99 server
 * var       STRING      0 99 server.hostname
 * var       STRING      0 99 server.identity
 * var       IP          0 99 server.ip
 * none      VOID       41 99 sess
 * var       STRING     41 99 sess.xid
 * action    VOID       40 41 set
 * none      VOID       40 41 storage
 * var       STEVEDORE  40 41 storage.s0
 * var       BYTES      40 41 storage.s0.free_space
 * var       BOOL       40 41 storage.s0.happy
 * var       BYTES      40 41 storage.s0.used_space
 * var       STEVEDORE  40 41 storage.Transient
 * var       BYTES      40 41 storage.Transient.free_space
 * var       BOOL       40 41 storage.Transient.happy
 * var       BYTES      40 41 storage.Transient.used_space
 * none      VOID       41 41 sub
 * action    VOID       40 41 synthetic
 * func      BOOL       40 41 true
 * action    VOID       40 41 unset
 * none      VOID       41 41 vcl
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_backend_error
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_backend_fetch
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_backend_response
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_deliver
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_fini
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_hash
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_hit
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_init
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_miss
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_pass
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_pipe
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_purge
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_recv
 * sub       VOID       40 41 vcl_synth
*/
```

However if I make a error in my VCL file, like replace `.host` with `host`, I get a VCC compiler error:

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Expected '.' got 'host'
(program line 93), at
('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 17 Pos 5)
    host = "127.0.0.1";
----####---------------


In backend specification starting at:
('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 16 Pos 1)
backend default {
#######----------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
VCL compilation failed
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong.

This is what the `-C` option does according to the docs:

```
Output VCL code compiled to C language
```

What you're seeing is the C representation of the VCL file. The VCC thread of the `varnishd` process will transpile the VLC code into C code. This C code will be compiled into machine code and the `.so` file that results from the compilation will be linked to the `varnishd` runtime process prior to execution.

As long as you're not making any syntax errors, the `-C` option will spit out the C code. Once you make a mistake in the VCL, the compilation will fail and you'll get an error.

### VCL validation with `varnishadm`

There are other ways to validate your VCL file.

You can either add your VCL code as an inline string to `varnishadm vcl.inline`. See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnish-cli.html#vcl-inline-configname-quoted-vclstring-auto-cold-warm for documentation.

You can also use the following commands to load, validate & discard the VCL file:

```
sudo varnishadm vcl.load validation default.vcl
sudo varnishadm vcl.discard validation
```

The first command will load the `default.vcl` file and try to compile it. When it success the `validation` configuration is stored and can be used in production through `varnishadm vcl.use validation`.

But we're not going to do that. Because this is only a validation run, we'll remove the `validation` config through `varnishadm vcl.discard validation` as seen in the example above.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, the compiler output is a bit confusing for first time users.